# Decompression of GZIP:ed response (Grails / Groovy)

Tags: rest, groovy, gzip, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm consuming a REST api using the RestBuilder plugin. I get a response where the body is compressed:

```
Content-Encoding=[gzip]
```

Does groovy/Grails provide any easy access / native methods for decoding gzip compression? The only thing I found is the native Java zip api (ex. GZIPInputStream). Does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring and HttpComponents will handle the decoding automatically:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        "some/url/", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders),
        String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

basically, you have 2 options here:

- `GZIPInputStream`
- configure GZIP-decompression in tomcat, see [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/)

Comment: I like the second option, but this requires me to configure the embedded tomcat instance so that the testing environment would be valid. I will think a bit about this.