# Decompressing REST response with GZIPInputStream

Tags: grails, groovy, gzip

I'm trying to decompress a gzip:ed response i receive from a REST service:

```
Content-Encoding=[gzip], Content-Type=[application/json], Content-Length=[710] ...
```

I'm using the Grails REST Client Builder Plugin:

```
def response = new RestBuilder().get(HOST + "/api/..."){
        contentType "application/json"
        accept "application/json"
}
```

The returned response is a Spring [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). I'm trying to decompress the data using `GZIPInputStream`:

```
String body = response.getBody()        
new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes())).text
```

This fails to `Caused by ZipException: Not in GZIP format`

Obviously there is something I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out what. All advice is appriciated.

Comment: This related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157605/decompression-of-gziped-response-grails-groovy).

Comment: Are you sure the rest client isn't handling the gzip encoding for you already? I'm not sure about the rest client builder plugin but I'm pretty sure Groovy's HTTPBuilder does.

Comment: What does `println body` show? I suspect you're trying to unzip it twice

Comment: @tim_yates _println body_ shows gibberish, sort of _?Mo?0_??J?3?b?_?8T?4?... but with other chars that are not allowed here. My interpretation is that it is still compressed.

Comment: Can you try adding `contentEncoding = ContentEncoding.Type.GZIP` in your closure?

Comment: @tim_yates `contentEncoding` does not seem to be a supported parameter. Throws exception "No signature method ...contentEncoding()".

Comment: @IanRoberts Actually I could not get it to work with Groovy's `HTTPBuilder`. The respons is otherwise ok, but responseData is `null`. The wrapped entity seems to contain a `org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity` and a lenght of 8810 - still its content is `null`. I get a proper `JSON` response if I enter the same URL in a browser, so something is wrong in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* need to keep using the Rest Client Builder you only need to modify your client code slightly:

```
def response = new RestBuilder().get(HOST + "/api/..."){
    contentType "application/json"
    accept byte[].class, "application/json" }
```

Note the extra parameter in the accept call - byte[].class - which signifies that RestTemplate should refrain from any parsing of the response.

To decompress you can now do:

```
new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body))
```

Yeah, I know, already answered with accept but some might still find it helpful in case switching Rest components is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

I never managed to get it to work with grails / groovy libraries, so i switched to spring and httpcomponents:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "some/url/", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders),
            String.class);
```

Which decoded gzip automatically and thus there are no longer any need for manual decoding.